# why does my gas fireplace pilot light go out after the flame on the logs reaches desired temperature

Tags: fireplace

why does my gas fireplace pilot light go out after the flame on the logs reaches desired temperature and turns off?pilot lights OK and has a steady blue flame but each time the logs light then turns off when the flame to the logs reaches desired temperature the pilot light also goes off

Comment: What does “reaches desired temperature” mean?  Does the fireplace have a thermostat?  Thus “reaching desired temperature” means the thermostat was satisfied turning the main burner off?  Is the pilot supposed to stay lit?  Some pilots don’t stay lit between cycles, others do.  If the pilot is improperly going out at the end of a main burner cycle the first step would be to determine if the pilot itself needs to be cleaned (carbon buildup) or adjusted so that it better heats the thermocouple.  It’s  also possible the thermocouple needs replacement, they don’t have infinite life.

Comment: i would try cleaning it, sounds like the o2 sensor is acting up. it might need replaced.

Comment: Has it always done this?  Is this a *new* gas fireplace?  Did it work okay before but stopped working?